# Getting None Type error when i am applying a statistical function to a RDD in pypspark

Tags: pyspark, rdd

```
filtered_data = filtered_data.map(lambda x: log(x.label))
```

Filtered_data is a Labelled Point RDD which serves as an input to a Linear regression model. It consists of 2 fields - label and feature vector.

Sample - `[LabeledPoint(1.0[0.4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]),
LabeledPoint(1.0[0.777778,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]),
 LabeledPoint(1.0, [0.95,0.162791,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.6976744186,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]),`

This is the command that i am trying to execute. It gives the following error.
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

```
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

When i try to perform any other operation such as addition or subtraction , It executes successfully.

Comment: are you sure you have no 0's or None/NULL in your x.label

Comment: is it possible to give us a minimum complete reproducible example ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have values between 1 and 4800. But when i take log, those 1's will be converted to zeroes